# How to Translate "Ship here" button

Tags: magento2.3, translate

I'm trying to translate a button when you are in checkout and you click "Add new address", a popup comes up where you can add a new address.

At the bottom on that popup there is 2 buttons, one called "Ship here" and one called
"Cancel" I would like to translate "Ship Here" but when i use Translate inline,  there is no option to translate this. Anyone here knows where i can find the code to translate the button? Can't seam to find it anywhere.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go down the route of installing a language pack and update the csv file for Ship Here

```
Ship Here,Save Address,module,Magento_Checkout,,
```

Comment: I do have a language pack, but ship here is not in the excel sheet. Do you know how i can do this.

Comment: Just add the extra line to the base of the excel sheet and upload and clear translation cache.

Comment: But don't i need to tell the excel sheet where it need to translate? Or will it do it automatically?

Comment: It will translate Ship Here across the board. 

Ship Here,Save Address,module,Magento_Checkout,,

Comment: Thank a lot mate!